# i cant intent from listview to new activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have a ListView which has data from a parsed xml. So this is my sample code:
I can't intent from list view to new activity

```
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);           
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

             String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
             String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();

             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
             i.putExtra(KEY_HEADLINE, title);
             i.putExtra(KEY_ARTICLEDATE, date);
             startActivity(i);
        }
      });
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing

Comment: What are you are getting? post the SingleMenuItemActivity along with the logcat error.

Comment: @user3086099 are you getting any errors? What is the problem in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getApplicationContext()` is almost always wrong. you need to pass the Context of the current Activity like [Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107219/ashish-kumar) said,
`getApplicationContext()` Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.
read more at [dev.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Application context in Intent. Pass Activity context.

```
         Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
         i.putExtra(KEY_HEADLINE, title);
         i.putExtra(KEY_ARTICLEDATE, date);
         startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `getApplicationContext()` from `OnItemClickListener` class, but it's a activity method.

For example, your activity name is `MyActivity`.
So You should call it as `MyActivity.this.getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
first You have to add
list.setClickable("true");

then, get the listview position
  Object o = lv.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
  int posix = Integer.parseInt(o.toString());

So, Final code will be..

list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);           
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setClickable("true");

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

             String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
             String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
 Object o = lv.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
  int posix = Integer.parseInt(o.toString());
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
             i.putExtra(KEY_HEADLINE, title);
             i.putExtra(KEY_ARTICLEDATE, date);
             startActivity(i);
        }
      });
```